# How not to load a script in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

It's possible to load a script *only* in IE with conditional comments

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

but what if I *don't* want to load it in IE lte 7 (but still need it in all other browsers)?

Any simple solutions?

P.S. I have a problem with SyntaxHighlighter - too many code slows IE7 down and since I'm short of time, I decided just to turn it off in IE7 for now.

Comment: Are you using a server-side language to generate your pages, or is it straight HTML?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx) says you can use the `!` (NOT) operator like `[if !IE]`

Comment: Greetings from 2014! For some reason `[if !IE]` does not seem to work for me. Any pointers anyone?

Answer (score 4):

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Won't this only work on versions of IE greater than 7?  Firefox will see the whole thing as a comment.

Comment: That's a good point, updated with a downlevel-revealed conditional.

Answer (score 4):

```
<![if !IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Comment: I don't think that is valid code. Doesn't conditional comments always start and end like regular comments (<!-- ... -->)?
In this example: <!--[if !IE]> ... <![endif]-->

Comment: This is a [down-level revealed comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx#dlrevealed) and is valid in all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

This syntax works good (the script wouldn't be commented in firefox, chrome and so on):

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try detecting the browser server-side and then echo the appropriate script includes.

The following has an example on simplistic browser detection in PHP:

http://www.php-scripts.com/20050912/12/

Answer (score 1):

Since conditional statements are not Working in IE (10,11) and only IE(11) is supported by Microsoft and if anyone is still looking at running IE specific JavaScript then this code still works tested in IE(11), and non IE browsers(Chrome,Firefox,Edge).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(/MSIE \d|Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
        {document.write('<script src="../nolng/js/ex1IE.js"><\/script>');}
    else 
        {document.write('<script src="../nolng/js/ex1.js"><\/script>'); // for Chrome,Firefox,Edge}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the examples shown here and elsewhere, and it is really frustrating to see how many places this code example is messed up. Turns out the answer is simple, IE has special 'conditionals' like [if IE], but other browsers need comments to work with the 'conditionals'.

For example, since JQuery 2 doesn't work with IE8, you can do something like this

```
<!--[if IE ]>  (following is only visible to IE)
    <script src="./js/lib/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>-->  (extra comment - only visible to non-IE)
    <script src="./js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

I have verified the above works in Firefox, Chrome, IE8, Dolphin mobile, and Chrome mobile. You can also specify version. For example, less than IE 9 would be: `<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>`

For a detailed explanation, check out http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/