# how can make a script to not execute on a certain page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Sorry for the title ,it is indeed confusing.

I have some javascript code that works in every browser except IE 7 and 8 (it throws errors). So as a work around I would like the code not to run on certaing pages of all browsers where its redundant.

I would like the solution to be in javascript because I only want to disable in some pages instead of apply the rule to all.

Comment: Wrap around with an if (browser = this and that) {...} ?

Comment: is this static pages or do you have some kind of server side code i.e. php or ruby? if there is server side code, wouldn't be better to sniff the user-agent and render the page accordingly?

Comment: @LajosVeres:the thing is i have a common js include on every page which consist of all the js scripts including the one that gives me error.Only for IE I want to disable this script.Is it possible.

Comment: If it just needs to be blocked for is, use conditional comments : `<!--[if IE 9]><script>……</script><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think for example this function can help you to skip the javascripts on javascript side:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or you can do this on php side also:

[PHP: If internet explorer 6, 7, 8 , or 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302302/php-if-internet-explorer-6-7-8-or-9)

Comment: thx for the answer..but i dont want to detect the browser..its just  some..lets say if there is a script that i just want to stop it to execute...thats my real question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IE conditional statements in the head tag to include JS only when the browser is IE of a specific version:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script src="myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The code is wrapped in a comment statement on purpose!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand you question well. But if you want disable the script of IE

You can try this(for example):

For disabline script for IE -

```
 <!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            // your inline script goes here
    </script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

[Read this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505155/how-not-to-load-a-script-in-ie)

For disabling script for IE 8 -

```
<!--[if !(IE 8)]><!-->
    <script src="path/to/external/script"></script>
    <script>
        // your inline script goes here
    </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and

```
<!--[if !(gte IE 8)]><!-->
    <script src="path/to/external/script"></script>
    <script>
        // your inline script goes here
    </script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

[Read this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692129/conditional-comment-for-except-ie8/1692600#1692600)

**Removing a Script block :**

set a id to your script,

```
 <script id="sample">
    ...
    </script>
```

and use this code,

```
 $("#sample").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<![if !IE]>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<![endif]>
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess what you're looking for is `document.location` in combination with a browser detectio. But be aware that most browsers can fake the instances. If you're using jQuery I'd suggest you use the `$.support` property instead of trying to get the user agent.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Greetings

Niveaulos