# How to stop a JavaScript function from running in IE but not in other browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a javascript function that runs on clicking a link in the site.

```
$('.mainNavWrap .preloadNav a, .bannerNav li a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $('.preloader2').fadeIn(100, redirectPage);
});
function redirectPage() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }, 1000);

}
```

The function calls a preloader before the page redirects. How can I disable this entire function for ie8?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999388/jquery-check-if-user-is-using-ie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505155/how-not-to-load-a-script-in-ie

Comment: @AnoopJoshi is right, just the same question. Detect user-agent and check with a regex if is in certain range. Btw there is a more spesific navigator object http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can try this:

```
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (msie > 0)
        {
           /* CODING SPECIFIC TO IE BROWSER */
           if (parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))) == 8)
           {   /* CODING SPECIFIC TO IE8*/}
        }   
        else                 
        {
             /* CODING FOR OTHER BROWSERS*/
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Method I*

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) $('.preloader2').fadeIn(100, redirectPage);
```

Note: This will not work in jQuery 1.9 or later unless the jQuery Migrate plugin is included.

*Method II*

([Detect IE version (prior to v9) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964966/detect-ie-version-in-javascript#))

Add it in html:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

then use it in your script:

```
if ($('html').is('.ie8')) $('.preloader2').fadeIn(100, redirectPage);
```

Comment: $.browser was removed in jquery 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Check for SVG support coz ie8 doesnot support ie8
following is the code:-

```
 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1) {
 if (!document.createElement('SVG').getAttributeNS) {
     if (document.createElement('DATA').getAttributeNS) {
       //the browser is defently IE8
         return;
      }
   }
}
else
{
//call your function
}
```

or another way is:-
function for checking ie8

```
function isIE () 
{
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
 }

 if (isIE () == 8) {
  // IE8 code
 } else {
   // Other versions IE or not IE
  }
```

Comment: Non IE8 browsers also don't support SVG, so you'd be hitting too many browsers with this method

Comment: then you can use 2nd method

Answer (score -1):

Have it return false if the user agent matches IE8. Usually browser sniffing is not suggested, but it's pretty much the only way without hitting more browsers than necessary.

[Here's a list of UA strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/)

```
  function redirectPage() {
        var ie = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(MSIE)/g) ? true : false );
       if (ie == true) {
    return false; // or browser-specific code
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }, 1000);
    }
    }
```

Wrote this from mobile, so pardon the formatting.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery has functionality for seeing if a browser is any form of MSIE

```
if (!$.browser.msie) {
   // jquery function
}
```

Comment: $.browser was removed in jquery 1.9