# Skip inclusion of d3.js for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, d3.js

I have a project that uses the latest version of d3 (v6), I include the api as follows in my index.html:

```
        <script src="scripts/d3.js"></script>
```

This version of d3 does not support IE, I get a console error as the ECMA version of Javascript in IE does not support => for example.

This is fine for me as I test if `window.d3` exists and if not then I show something else instead of my d3 chart.

But I would like to not have this console error.

So how do I only include d3.js if the browser is not IE?

Thanks

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505155/how-not-to-load-a-script-in-ie. If you're feeling ambitious, you also might be able to transpile an IE compatible version of d3 with babel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the browser `userAgent` to check if it is IE, if not then load the d3 script.

You can refer to the code below, it works well and clear d3 console error in IE 11:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
        if (!(msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))) //If not IE, load d3 script
        {
            document.write('<script src="scripts/d3.js"><\/script>');
        } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg>
        <circle class="target" style="fill: #69b3a2" stroke="black" cx=50 cy=50 r=40></circle>
    </svg>
    <script>
        if (window.d3) {
            d3.select(".target").style("stroke-width", 8);
        }
        else {
            alert("IE");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```